# Is there a way to do a reverse update with Subversion?

Tags: svn, vendor-branch

I have a branch in an SVN tree which contains the source to a third party product. I need to update that branch with the latest version. If I check it out and copy the new source over the old source, I can easily add the new files and do a commit. However, I would also like make sure that any files that are the old version but not the new version get deleted.

Is there a way to tell SVN to update a repository from a directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a tool to do that. It's documented in the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.org), more precisely in the part about [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html#svn.advanced.vendorbr.svn_load_dirs).